# How is ruby code executed

Tags: ruby, interpreter

I have recently started to learn Ruby. I know that Ruby is a interpreted language(even though "every" language is since it is interpreted by the CPU as machine code). But how does the ruby interpreter convert the code written in Ruby to machine code? I have read that the interpreter do not read the source code, but byte code, however I do never have to compile as I do in Java. So, is this yet another thing that Ruby does for you? And if it does, does it generate the byte code at runtime? Because you never get a .class file as you do in Java. And on top of it all I read about Just-In-Time compilators that obviously does something to the byte code so it runs faster.

If the above is the case does the interpreter first scan through all of the source code, convert it into byte code and then compiles it another time with JIT at runtime?

And last I AM NOT looking for an answer with the performance aspect of this, I just want to know how it is processed, which stages it goes through and in what time it does so.

Thanks for your time.

I am using this interpeter http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/

Comment: From your question, should we assume you use JRuby, the Java implementation of ruby?

Comment: No I am using the standard from the Ruby website.

Comment: JIT? You mean android Jit? you using jruby in android?

Comment: ohh , Just-In-Time compilators ... ok ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *But how does the ruby interpreter convert the code written in Ruby to machine code?*

It doesn't, at least not all the implementations.

Afaik only [Rubinius](http://rubini.us/) is trying to do what you describe, that's compiling to machine code.

> *I have read that the interpreter do not read the source code, but byte code, however I do never have to compile as I do in Java. So, is this yet another thing that Ruby does for you?*

Yes

> *And if it does, does it generate the byte code at runtime?*

Yeap, pretty much. And keeps it in memory. The tradeof is the next time it has to read->translate->execute all over again.

> *If the above is the case does the interpreter first scan through all of the source code, convert it into byte code and then compiles it another time with JIT at runtime?*

Not all the source code, just what it needs. Then yes, create a bytecode representation keeps it in memory, and not necessarily that is compiled to machine code.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! I have updated my post to show with interpreter I use. I think I understand it know. You say that only the source code needed is converted to byte code, what does this mean? That only the source code needed for the objects, methods etc. that the program use is converted? And then the converted source code will be stored in the interpreter so that next time(if I do not change anything) will execute faster(even though it am not out for performance, just understanding). So the interpreter only understand to execute the bytecode generated right?

Comment: And one more thing that I need to add, the bytecode that the interpreter reads is eventually evaluted into machine code ofcourse right? And if it was a JIT compiler it would take the bytecode and make something magic happen to that as-well?

Comment: What OscarRyz says is accurate for Ruby 1.9. Ruby 1.8 was a much simpler true interpreter that walked the AST.

Answer (score 3):

The standard implementation of Ruby1.8 uses an interpreter called [MRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_MRI) (Matz's  Ruby Interpreter). This is a program that is compiled to machine code that:

1. Reads the text files into a data structure.
2. Follows the instructions in the data structure to decide what to do